# Angular 6: Fetch Hash Table Data from JSON respond Backend

Tags: json, angular, typescript, interface, hashmap

I have This JSON respond from my backend:

```js
//User_Courses

[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Ice King",
    email: "pretty_princess1234@gmail.com"
    completedCourses: [1,3],
    unlockedCourses:  [1,3,4,5,6],
    completedLessons: [{"1" => [1,2,3]}, {"3" => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}, {"4" => [1]}]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mr. Crocker",
    email: "fairy_godparents111@gmail.com"
    completedCourses: [3],
    unlockedCourses:  [1,3,4],
    completedLessons: [{"3" => [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}, {"4" => [1,2]}]
  }
]

// completed lessons are all the lesson the user finished. 
// courses can be in progress or completed.
```

I want to fetch data from backend and subscribe it to this interface.
I don't sure how to implement the data structure and how to access data. 
This is the interface I created:

```js
export interface IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  completedCourses: number[];
  unlockedCourses: number[];
  completedLessons: // <----- don't know what type to write
}
```

I want to know how to implement this, subscribe data with service and access data (in order to change it later and add data).
Thank you so much!

Comment: `completedLessons: any[]` sounds fitting.

Comment: and how I subscribe the data and access it?

Comment: you can use array of this type: ```interface CompletedLesson{[name:string]:number[]}```

Comment: ok that's sounds good. then how I subscribe to it? do I need to do something special or subscribe like I usually do?

Comment: and is CompletedLesson is array? can I make it array by adding []?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create model for *CompletedLesson* (as mentioned in the comments):

```
interface ICompletedLesson {
    [name: string]: number[];
}

interface IUser {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    completedCourses: number[];
    unlockedCourses: number[];
    completedLessons: ICompletedLesson[];
}
```

Then, create a *service*, something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(private http: HttpService) { }

    fetchUserCourses(): Observable<IUser[]> {
        return this.http.get<IUser[]>(`URL_TO_THE_USER_COURSES%);
    }
}
```

And, wherever you are fetching data (some *component* for example):

```
fetchUserCourses() {
    // userService is injected in this component's constructor
    this.userService.fetchUserCourses().subscribe(users => {
        // do something with result, yes, something like
        this.users = users;
    });
}
```

In the JSON you provided, to access the first lesson of the *Mr. Crocker* completed lessons (`this.users` are all users you retrieved from backend):

```
const firstCompletedLesson = this.users[1].completedLessons[0];   // {"3": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
const lessons = firstCompletedLesson["3"];  // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
const firstLesson = lessons[0];  // 1
```

Furhermore, you can access "3" like this:

```
Object.keys(firstCompletedLesson)[0];   // 3
```

and you can add to array using *push*:

```
lessons.push(8);   // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

and to add new completed lesson use:

```
this.users[1].completedLessons.push({ "5": [1, 2, 3] });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you! what do you mean do something with result? something like this.users = users?

Comment: how do I access for e.x the first lesson in the array? for e.x if I have [{"3": [1,2,3]}] so how I print lesson 1?

Comment: I edited the answer, check if this edit answers your comment questions...

Comment: yeah that's good! is there a way to access "3" somehow? to check if the course id is the correct one?

Comment: and how I add to existed array lesson and how I add new hash?

Comment: Check the edit again, should have answered the rest of the questions...